# Definition of absolute and relative precision

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, precision

I am currently brushing up on my stats knowledge and I am struggling with the notion of absolute precision and relative precision.

From what I've read so far, precision is used to specify the range of a confidence interval. I know this can also be done using the confidence level and this notion is related to precision as follows:

Suppose we are given a sample $X$ of size $n$ and suppose (for simplicity) that we know the variance $\sigma^2$ of the target population. Then for a given confidence level (call it q) we find the related $z$ - score $z_q$ and construct the confidence interval as
$$
\big(\bar X - z_q\cdot\sigma_{\bar X}, \;\bar X + z_q\cdot\sigma_{\bar X}\big) \quad \text{or equivalently} \quad \bar X \pm z_q\cdot\sigma_{\bar X} 
$$ 
where $\bar X$ denotes the sample mean and $\sigma_{\bar X} = \sigma / \sqrt n$ the standard error.

Now given this information, the absolute precision is 
$$
D = z_q\cdot\sigma_{\bar X}
$$
whilst the relative precision is
$$
r = \frac{z_q\cdot\sigma_{\bar X}}{\bar X} \,.
$$

This is my current understanding of absolute and relative precision.

On the other hand, the source that I am using for my studies states absolute precision and relative precision in terms of the true population parameter as follows:

1. Absolute precision D is specified as $D = \bar X - \mu$
2. relative precision r is given by $D = r\mu$.

How does this give me a precise answer for $D$ and $r$ if the parameter $\mu$ is unknown ?

Comment: Your source seems to be using "precision" in a sense similar to "bias," which is often interpreted as *accuracy*.  Are you sure you have interpreted this source correctly?

Comment: @whuber I have given the specification pretty much word for word, though I must admit that the source is very concise and rather scant in explanation. However, except for the last paragraph the explanation above is my own -- would you say that this understanding of precision (i.e. the description above the last paragraph) is correct ? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @harlekin What is the source you used?